# Xamarin add and place entry dynamically

Tags: android, xamarin

I am a beginner in Xamarin and coding and I am trying to add an entry dynamically with Button Clicked Event.
I managed to place a new entry with the help of some older answers here like this: 
[How to add entry fields dynamically during run time in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301250/how-to-add-entry-fields-dynamically-during-run-time-in-xamarin-forms)

However, I don't know how to define the position of the new entry in my layout.
It places the entry at the bottom.

[image: example]

My XAML - Code

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="EntriesStackLayout">
        <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="20" RowSpacing="20">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Entry Placeholder="Label" x:Name="EntryTag" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Button Text="Attribut hinzufügen"  Grid.Row="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

My XAML CS - Code

```
int x = 1;

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddEntry(EntriesStackLayout, "Attribut " + x.ToString());
        x++;
    }
    private void AddEntry(StackLayout sl, string name)
    {
        Entry entry = new Entry() { Placeholder = name,
        };
        sl.Children.Add(entry);
    }
```

Comment: you are using a StackLayout, which just stacks controls vertically one after the other.  How do you want to place your new Entry control?

Comment: i would love to playe the Entry between the first entry and the button or in other words above the button. should i try it with grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your `Entry` in a `StackLayout`

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="EntriesStackLayout">
        <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="20" RowSpacing="20">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackLayout x:Name="InnerEntries" Grid.Row="0">
              <Entry Placeholder="Label" x:Name="EntryTag" />
            </StackLayout>
            <Button Text="Attribut hinzufügen"  Grid.Row="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
      </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

then add the new entries to that StackLayout

```
AddEntry(EntriesStackLayout, "Attribut " + x.ToString());
```